# Search by number starts with in spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data jpa, MySQL.
I have following Entity

```
User {
    BigDecimal userNo;
    String name;
}
```

Mysql table looks like,

```
user(userNo decimal(10, 0), name text);
```

I want to search all `users` whose `userNo` **starts with** say for example 12.
How can I do it in spring data jpa.

I tried using,

```
userDao.findByUserNoStartingWith(BigDecimal userNo);
```

But it is not working and throw exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [12%] did not match expected type [java.math.BigDecimal (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [12%] did not match expected type [java.math.BigDecimal (n/a)]

How can I search using derived query or jpa Query ?

Comment: the column is a decimal number not a string.

Comment: Yes got it. but what is solution over it

Comment: `select * from user where userNo >= 12` ?

Comment: it will return 13 which i do not want

Comment: hmm maybe u don't have `userNo == 12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to write a query that does something like

```
select *
from   user
where  cast(userNo as char) like 12%
```

Since Spring Data cannot generate such a query by itself, you'll have to specify it yourself. Since the `cast` is not JPQL, you'll also have to tell Spring Data it's a native SQL query.

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, BigDecimal> {
    @Query(value = "select u from user u where cast(userNo as char) like :userNo%",
           native = true)
    public List<User> find(@Param("userNo") String userNo);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do its pageable instead of list? Is there any way for it?

Comment: Yes, paging is supported; see [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e112) for more info.

Comment: Yes paging is supported but not for native query. and without native query I cant perform "startsWith" on decimal type

Comment: @Prashant Shilimkar Can use LIMIT, OFFSET haaha ;)